# MongoDB - Operations with nested fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have twitter data that looks like this:

```
db.users.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("578ffa8e7eb9513f4f55a935"),
    "user_name" : "koteras",
    "retweet_count" : 0,
    "tweet_followers_count" : 461,
    "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
    "coordinates" : null,
    "tweet_mentioned_count" : 1,
    "tweet_ID" : "755891629932675072",
    "tweet_text" : "RT @ochocinco: I beat them all for 10 straight hours #FIFA16KING",
    "user" : {
        "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2011-12-27T09:04:01Z"),
        "FavouritesCount" : 5223,
        "FollowersCount" : 461,
        "FriendsCount" : 619,
        "UserId" : 447818090,
        "Location" : "501"
    }
```

For example, I want to find the number of users that have "FollowersCount" greater than "FavouritesCount". How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator is specifically designed for this.

```
db.users.find( { $where: function() { return (this.user.FollowersCount > this.user.FavouritesCount) } } );
```

But keep in mind that this would run single threaded JS code, and will be slower.

Another option is to use an aggregation pipeline projecting the difference, and then having a `$match` on the difference

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    diff: {$subtract: ["$user.FollowersCount", "$user.FavouritesCount"]},
    // project remaining fields here
    }
  },
  {$match: {diff: {$gt: 0}}}
])
```

In my experience I have found the second one to be much faster than the first.

Comment: And in both cases, apply `itcount()` to the returned cursor to get the count of matching documents

Comment: Thanks man! What about the "and" function? If i want to find tweets that contain certain text and from specific location.

Comment: Ive tried this and it doesnt workdb.users.find({$and [{"user.Location": "501"},{ tweet_text: /UEFA/}]})

Comment: Thr's no need for `$and` in this. `workdb.users.find({"user.Location": "501", tweet_text: /UEFA/})` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of users that have "FollowersCount" greater than "FavouritesCount", you could use the aggregation framework which has some operators that you can apply.

Consider the first use case which looks at manipulating the comparison operators within the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline and a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline to filter documents based on the **[`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#exp._S_cmp)** value. You can then get the final user count by applying a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline that aggregates the filtered documents:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {               
            "hasMoreFollowersThanFavs": { 
                "$cmp": [ "$user.FollowersCount", "$user.FavouritesCount" ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "hasMoreFollowersThanFavs": 1 } },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

---

Another option is using a single pipeline with **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator which incorporates the functionality of **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** as above and returns all documents which match a specified condition using **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** system variable and discards those that don't match using the **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** system variable:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$eq": [
                        { "$cmp": [ "$user.FollowersCount", "$user.FavouritesCount" ] }, 
                        1
                    ]
                }, 
                "$$KEEP", 
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },  
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```